# Difference between using junit setup() method and calling a method from the tests itself

Tags: java, junit

I tried looking for this over StackOverflow and even Google, but either I am using wrong keywords to find my answer or there is no direct answer yet.

My question is, is there a difference in performance or functionalities between using the setup() method and calling a method from within the test itself?

For example:

1. Tests with a setup method annotated with @Before annotation, which is called for each test run.

   ```
   public class TestSetup extends TestCase {
       private String name;

       @Before
       public void setup(  ) {
           this.name = "abc";
       }

       @Test
       public void test1() { assertEquals("xyz", this.name); }

       @Test
       public void test2() { assertEquals("abc", this.name); }
   }
   ```
2. Writing a test which calls a method before executing.

   ```
   public class TestSetup extends TestCase {
       private String name;

       public void setName() {
           this.name = "abc";
       }

       @Test
       public void test1() {
           setName();
           assertEquals("xyz", this.name);
       }

       @Test
       public void test2() {
           setName();
           assertEquals("abc", this.name);
       }
   }
   ```

What difference does this make except for the fact that in the latter case, the programmer needs to be aware that (s)he has to call the setup functions for the ones (s)he actually wants to use it.

Comment: ideally, your setUp() method should contain code to create pre-conditions to execute the testXX() . The testXXX() method should conceptually have nothing to do with setting up data / preconditions for test. Same is the logic for tearDown() method. Thus, if you get exception/error in your testXXX() method, it should be due to error in your code being tested, not due some issues with initialization()/ cleanUp()

Answer (score 0):

Setup method is used for  pre-conditions like object/resource `initialization` like `mock object,softassertions` object etc .Its upto developers whether to use the method or not .`Junit/TestNg what ever framework you take all the common object s intialization/object creation will be done in setup i.e @Before annotation`. Moreover you know that `@Before` will be called prior to the execution of test case.
Though for simple test method it wont't cause any impacts in your logic but for bulk classes with many test methods it may cause `RunTimeException` or even error `related to`method area in JVM`or PermGen` space if you keep on calling the same method stack.

To overcome this  the same logic you can write in setup method once instead of calling same method multiple times unless you need different logic .

Hope you got the context of setup method.